# Jquery Validate max conforme condição

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Estou fazendo um `jquery.validate`, conseguir fazer o max ser dinamicamente,
algo como:

```
...
    max: function () {
    return $('#QtdEstoqueHidden').val();
...
```

ok, funcionou! (armazeno o valor max em um campo hidden que é substituido dinamicamente por um ajax na página)

**Agora quero fazer com que dependendo de um `<select>` esse `max` seja ignorado.**

Tentei fazer ele ignorar a validação, mas não consegui, então tentei fazer um max = 999999999 seria suficiente como se ingorasse. porém não consegui.
Agora ele sempre libera o formulário.

Segue o jsfiddler
https://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/9nmzntqs/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode mudar as regras dinâmicamente!

Adicionei o trecho abaixo no fiddle para demonstrar.

Quando houver mudança no combobox e se o valor for 0 ele remove a regra, senão ele retorna a regra.

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
            debug: false,
            success: "valid"
        });
        $("#FormMov").validate({
            rules: {
                Quantidade: {
                    required: true,
                   max: function() {
                      var maxValue = $('#QtdEstoqueHidden').val();
                        return parseInt(maxValue);

                  }
                }
            },
            messages: {
                Quantidade: {
                    required: "é obrigatório",
                    max: "O valor deve conter um número menor que {0}"
                }
            }
        });
         $('select[name=TipoMovimentacao]').change(function(){
          if ($('select[name=TipoMovimentacao]').val() == 0) {
              console.log("remove regra");
                $('#Quantidade').rules('remove');
             }else{
            $('#Quantidade').rules('add', {
                max: function () {
                console.log("adiciona regra");
                        var maxValue = $('#QtdEstoqueHidden').val();
                        return parseInt(maxValue);
                    }
            });
             }
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<form action="#" id="FormMov" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  Max: <input type="text" id="QtdEstoqueHidden" value="43">
  <hr>
  <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantidade must be a number." data-val-required="The Quantidade field is required." id="Quantidade" name="Quantidade" type="number" value="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
  <select class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Tipo Movimentacao field is required." id="TipoMovimentacao" name="TipoMovimentacao" aria-invalid="false"><option value="">Selecione o tipo</option>
<option value="0">Ilimitado</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">Limitar Max</option>
<option value="2">Limitar Max 2</option>
</select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: amigo, no seu fiddle também ainda não funciona..se eu selecionar a opção Limitar Max, ele deveria limitar o valor que eu digito, no seu exemplo apesar do max ser 43 aceita 32412312, e se eu selecionar ilimitado..ai ele deveria ignorar.

Comment: ele valida e solta uma exceção e não permite continuar com o submit do formulário... ou você que ele não permite digitar nenhum número maior que o estipulado?

Comment: Se for caso tu pode alterar o atributo `max` do input `type='number'` de acordo com as condições que te atenderem.

Comment: vc não entendeu..estou digitando 10000 no campo input e ele está aceitando..o max não está validando quando deveria validar

Comment: Estranho, mas acho que resolvi, ele não aceita diretamente o retorno do `$().val()`, coloquei um `parseInt`, atualizei o código, veja se lhe atende.

Comment: veja, https://s3.postimg.org/l8n6o8roj/Limitar.png
apesar de estar como Limitar Max ele está deixando eu digitar um número maior ao max.

Comment: Ele mostra a mensagem quando perde o foco do input: https://postimg.org/image/jaf1bpy47/

Comment: no meu chrome não aparece isso! eu até consigo clicar no botão enviar.

Comment: você está testando o trecho na resposta do stackoverflow, onde tem o botão excetuar?  O código é apenas um exemplo pra demonstrar a funcionalidade, você deve adapta-lo a sua necessidade.

Comment: não, no fidller q vc postou, ops...foi mal..vou testar.